# If $f$ is an entire function which of the following is/are correct?

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity

> Consider the function $$f(z)=\frac {\sin (\frac {\pi z} {2})} {\sin (\pi z)}.$$ Then $f$ has poles at
>
> $1.$ $\ $ all integers.
>
> $2.$ $\ $ all even integers.
>
> $3.$ $\ $ all odd integers.
>
> $4.$ $\ $ all integers of the form $4k+1$, $\ k \in \Bbb Z$.

What I have thought is as follows $:$

If $z_0$ is a pole of $f$ then it is not a zero of $\sin \left (\frac {\pi z} {2} \right )$. Because if $z_0$ was a zero of $\sin \left (\frac {\pi z} {2} \right )$ then it can't be a zero of $\cos \left (\frac {\pi z} {2} \right )$ and hence $z_0$ becomes a removable singularity of $f$ which contradicts the fact that $z_0$ is a pole of $f$. Hence $z_0$ is indeed not a zero of
$\sin \left (\frac {\pi z} {2} \right )$. Hence $$\lim_{z \rightarrow z_0} f(z) = \lim_{z \rightarrow z_0} \frac {1} {\cos \left (\frac {\pi z} {2} \right )}.$$ On the other hand since $z_0$ is a pole of $f$ so $$\lim_{z \rightarrow z_0} f(z) = \infty.$$ i.e. $$\lim_{z \rightarrow z_0} \frac {1} {\cos \left (\frac {\pi z} {2} \right )}=\infty.$$ This shows that $z_0$ is a pole of $\frac {1} {\cos \left (\frac {\pi z} {2} \right )}$ i.e. $z_0$ is a zero of $\cos \left (\frac {\pi z} {2} \right )$. Therefore $\frac {\pi z} {2} = (2n+1)\frac {\pi} {2},\ n \in \Bbb Z$ $\implies$ $z = 2n+1,\ n \in \Bbb Z$. This shows that the poles of $f$ are all the odd integers.

Comment: The last sentence needs an obvious correction.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy sir would you please tell me where am I doing mistake?

Comment: Sorry sir I have made this correction. Now is it ok?

Comment: Yes, 3) is the correct answer.

Comment: $(4)$ is also a correct option as the set of all odd integers includes the integers of the form $4k+1,\ k \in \Bbb Z$.

Comment: Surely $f$ has poles at $4k+1$ too.

Comment: The title is currently incorrect. An [Entire function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entire_function) does **not** have any poles in the finite plane.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\sin(\pi z) = 2 \sin(\pi z/2) \cos(\pi z/2)$.

Answer (score 0):

We have:

$ \mathbb Z= \{z \in \mathbb C: \sin(\pi z)=0\}$

and

$2 \mathbb Z=\{z \in \mathbb C: \sin(\pi z/2)=0\}$.

Hence $f$ has a pole in $z \iff z \in \mathbb Z \setminus 2 \mathbb  Z$.